# Js framework loaded just one time and reused multiple time by other requests

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In the same page I want to put multiple full calendars. The problem is that for each calendar (100 calendar in my page) the calendar js scripts are reloaded each time (full calendar.js, moment.js, jquery.js) and that is very bad for the loading speed. Is there a way to say to the navigator or the code : keep the first loading in memory and reuse it instead of reload new scripts.

There is the idea of my code :

page1.php :

```html
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <th  scope="row">Monday</th>
        <td >
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="page2.php?cell=140?day=Monday">                  </iframe>
           </div>
        </td>
```

and my page2.php :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="js/basket.full.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src='fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar1.min.js'></script>
  <link href='fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar1.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header:false,
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      aspectRatio: 1,
      slotEventOverlap:false,
      slotLabelFormat: 'H',
      defaultDate: <?php echo json_encode($result[$dayNumber]); ?>,
      allDaySlot:false,
      navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: false,
      eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
      eventRender:
        function(event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.activity);

      },
      views: {
        agendaDay: {
        minTime: "09:00:00",
        maxTime: "19:00:00",
      }},
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'event.php?cell=<?php echo json_encode($cell);?>', // use the `url` property
          textColor: 'black'
        }]
    });

  });

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clearly your setup is wrong, looks like you're trying to implement single page application but you're referencing the files on all pages. How about you share what stack you're using, and how your layout pages are constructed as well as your subpages.

Comment: firstly consider caching the files you are using... if the data is little consider using localstore to save the data in user browser - finaly if posible consider using a more robost framework like react

Comment: you should only need to load fullCalendar, jquery, and momentJS files _once_ for the _whole_ page. You don't need to declare them again for each calendar. They are re-usable. TBH though if you are simultaneously loading 100 calendars into your page it's going to be pretty slow anyway, and very confusing for the user. Or is that not your setup? It's not totally clear since your description is a bit vague and you provided no code.